# Java Script Object Getting Stuck on Edge

Tags: javascript, object

What's really weird, is that in this java script code, when you move the circle object with WASD or the arrow keys, it works fine, but when it hits a corner or edge, it gets stuck. Try it out, and you'll see what I mean. I could not figure this out. Does anyone know why?

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(1600, 850);
}

var [xpos, ypos, xspeed, yspeed] = [225, 225, 0, 0];

function draw() {
    background(202, 191, 255);
    
    fill(0);
    text("Use the arrow keys (or WASD) to move the circle around", 25, 25);

    fill(0, 255, 0);
  rect(xpos, ypos, 75, 75, 75 * Math.PI);
    
    if(xpos >= 0 && xpos + 50 <= 1600) xpos += xspeed;
    if(ypos >= 0 && ypos + 50 <= 850) ypos += yspeed;
}

function keyPressed() {
    switch(keyCode) {
        case 37:
        case 65:
            xspeed = -2;
            break;
        case 39:
        case 68:
            xspeed = 2;
            break;
        case 38:
        case 87:
            yspeed = -2;
            break;
        case 40:
        case 83:
            yspeed = 2;
            break;
    }
}

function keyReleased() {
    switch(keyCode) {
        case 37:
        case 65:
            xspeed = 0;
            break;
        case 39:
        case 68:
            xspeed = 0;
            break;
        case 38:
        case 87:
            yspeed = 0;
            break;
        case 40:
        case 83:
            yspeed = 0;
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>HTML Game</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: lonnie best is right. I'm looking for a way to fix it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to 'fix' this by adding a notion of speed or direction to your movement calculations. This is what I did for the x direction:

```
if(xpos >= -1 && xpos + 50 <= 1600 && xspeed > 0){
  xpos += xspeed;
} 
if(xpos >= 0 && xpos <= 1600 && xspeed < 0){
  xpos += xspeed;
}
if(ypos >= -1 && ypos + 50 <= 850 && yspeed > 0){
  ypos += yspeed;
} 
if(ypos >= 0 && ypos <= 850 && yspeed < 0){
  ypos += yspeed;
}
```

The important bit here is the xspeed > 0 or xspeed < 0. I also noticed that xpos was getting set to -1 (subtracting by twos will get you there). So I updated the boundary case. I'd try the same on the y axis.

Good luck and happy hacking!

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with this portion of your code:

```
if(xpos >= 0 && xpos + 50 <= 1600) xpos += xspeed;
if(ypos >= 0 && ypos + 50 <= 850) ypos += yspeed;
```

Once the circle's location is not in the range handled above, it can never escape that (exceeded) edge. You need to add logic for all possible locations the circle can move to. For example, if the circle's x-position makes it to `-1` or `1551` it won't escape those exceeded-edges because your code doesn't account for that possibility.